# What is difference between "[self] in" & "[weak self] in" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, unsafe, weak

I just found out that I can write  "[self]" in the closures instead of [weak self] in but I'm not sure if it is safe or not.

more detail:

Before:

```
func roundShape(corners: CACornerMask, radius: CGFloat) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            layer.cornerRadius = radius
            layer.maskedCorners = corners
        }
    }
```

Now:

```
 func roundShape(corners: CACornerMask, radius: CGFloat) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
           layer.cornerRadius = radius
           layer.maskedCorners = corners
      }
  }
```

So please light me up if you know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing `[self]` is same as leaving the closure as it is meaning it could cause retain cycle unlike `[weak self]` , BTW  no need for any of them with `DispatchQueue.main.async {` as GCD queues don't hold a strong reference to `self`

Answer (score 3):

**Weak self** is a concept of **ARC**, which is mainly used to avoid retain cycle. If you directly use **self**, then it creates a **strong reference** and will not be removed from the memory. Consequently, the object that holds the variable will stay alive and leads to memory leakage. In order to overcome this issue, **weak self** must be used, which instantly releases the memory once the job is done.

**Note**: Weak self is an **Optional** so you can use **optional chaining** to access variables.